# SqlDataAdapter Issue

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I am just fixing a bug in existing web app. I am getting an error

> connection is already opened, and it cannot be opened again

issue before. So I introduced a property and it will check the connection, if it still open then it will close the connection and return the connection object.

We are using the `SqlDataAdapter` to fill a `DataSet`. We have tested with around 5 to 10 users. But its not creating any problem, but its creating the problem in the production.

It says `IndexoutOfRangeException`. Cannot find table 0

Here is the code

Before:

```
 Private conn1 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DataSource").ConnectionString)
 Private ds As New DataSet
    Dim daSTYi As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("EXECUTE dbo.getStayInfo '" & StayID & "'", conn1 )

                daSTYi.Fill(ds)
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
   Do operation
```

Now:

```
Private _Db As SqlConnection
    Public ReadOnly Property conn As SqlConnection
        Get
            If _Db IsNot Nothing Then
                If _Db.State = ConnectionState.Open Then _Db.Close()
                Return _Db 
            End If
            _Db = New SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DataSource").ConnectionString)
            Return _Db
        End Get
    End Property

    Dim daSTYi As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("EXECUTE dbo.getStayInfo '" & StayID & "'", conn)

                daSTYi.Fill(ds)

                If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
```

Any guess for the cause of the error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you execute a stored-procedure you need `daSTYi = New SqlDataAdapter("getStayInfo")` and  `daSTYi.SelectCommand.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure` and  You should also use parameters.

Comment: `Return _cdcsDb`...what is `_cdcsDb`?

Comment: @DMason - Its was a typo and i had correct that.

Comment: I guess the Fill statement doesn't create a table in your dataset (reason is probably what tim schmelter said) ... so when you access ds.Tables(0) the IndexOutofRangeException is thown ...